# R tm package's `removeWords` not removing twitter hashtags from tweets due to #

Tags: r, tm

I am trying to remove hashtags from tweets using `tm`'s function `removeWords`. The hashtags start with `#` as you know, and I want to remove these tags in their entirety. However, `removeWords` doesn't remove them:

```
> library(tm)
> removeWords(x = "WOW it is cool! #Ht https://google.com", words = c("#Ht", "https://google.com"))

[1] "WOW it is cool! #Ht "
```

If I remove the `#` from the `words` argument, the tag is removed:

```
> removeWords(x = "WOW it is cool! #Ht https://google.com", words = c("Ht", "https://google.com"))
[1] "WOW it is cool! # "
```

Which leaves the orphan `#` behind.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the function remove the words as-is simply, or am I missing something? The [manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tm/versions/0.7-7/topics/removeWords) is not very helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't think of a great way around it.  The reason behind what you're seeing is that removeWords relies on using regular expressions with word boundaries.  Unfortunately "#" doesn't count as a word boundary so it gets ignored essentially.  I hope to see a better answer with a nice workaround but you might just need to do something simple like an initial pass where you replace "#" with some keyword that you add to your list of things to remove in place of the symbol and use that keyword in place of the hashtag when creating your list of words to remove.

Comment: Or maybe a subsequent pass on the texts to remove all the orphan `#` (imagine if you have 10m tweets though).
I am also hoping for a more elegant and efficient way, ideally with one pass over the data to remove `m` hashtags from `n` tweets. Thanks!

Comment: Re-reading my post I hope I didn't give the wrong impression.  I think you could very easily do this directly using something like `gsub` combined with `lapply` or something.  The main issue is that I don't think you can do what you want to do directly using the `removeWords` function due to how it is coded and the way regular expressions define word boundaries.

Comment: That will require multiple passes also @Dason. I'm thinking of a method to do the replacement in a single pass, but I'm not sure it is easily accesible

Comment: I've updated and undeleted my answer. I think this should remove all hashtags from a string in single pass and can be adapted with sapply etc. to multiple strings

Comment: Deducing from other answers it appears there is no way to achieve this with `tm` efficiently. As this answer has addressed the question directly I accept it.

@Julian_Hn by the way there is an awesome algorithm out there called `flashtext`, which is extremely efficient and can replace all keywords from a lump of texts in a single pass. It is implemented in `python` but I haven't found it in `R`, so I resort to other options and RE-based solutions.

Comment: If you are free to call python code on your setup you could look into ```reticulate``` to call the python function

Answer (score 1):

You could use functions from the textclean package to help you with this.

```
library(textclean)
txt <- "WOW it is cool! #Ht https://google.com"

# remove twitter hashes
txt <- replace_hash(txt)
# remove urls
txt <- replace_url(txt)

txt
[1] "WOW it is cool!  "
```

To incorporate this inside tm, use tm_map to call these functions

```
...
# after creating corpus
my_corpus <- tm_map(my_corpus, content_transformer(replace_hash))
my_corpus <- tm_map(my_corpus, content_transformer(replace_url))
....
# rest of code
```

Comment: Won't this delete all hashtags? I think he only wants specific hashtags replaced?

Comment: @Julian_Hn, yep, this would remove all hastags (or replace them with something). It all depends on what you exactly want to achieve with textmining / sentiment analysis. That is not clear from the OP's question. I tend to remove the hashes and replace them with something else when textmining, but remove them (in most cases) for sentiment analysis.

Comment: The package is neat, I tried it and it works. Since I have surrounding metadata I used `VCorpus(DataframeSource(data))`.
However, as indicated by @Julian_Hn, it is exhaustive and it removes all words starting with `#`.

Answer (score 0):

Not using package tm but `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

replaceHashtags <- function(str,tags)
{
  repl <- rep("",length(tags))
  names(repl) <- tags
  return(stringr::str_replace_all(str, repl))
}

ExStr <- "WOW it is cool! #Ht #tag2 https://google.com"
Extags <- c("#Ht","#tag2")
replaceHashtags(ExStr,Extags)

[1] "WOW it is cool!   https://google.com"
```

This removes all matched hashtags specified in tags from a single string.
To apply this to multiple strings just use `sapply` etc.

Answer (score 0):

What a nice question! It's a bit tricky: when you look at the source code of [`tm::removeWords()`](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/R/transform.R?view=markup&revision=1531&root=tm), you'll see what it does:

```
gsub(sprintf("(*UCP)\\b(%s)\\b",
             paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE), collapse = "|")),
     "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

It works with word boundaries as @Dason mentions, that's why it's so complicated to extract hashtags. But you can use that as an inspiration to build your own function:

```r
# some tweets
tweets <- rep("WOW it is cool! #Ht https://google.com", times = 1e5)
remove <- c("#Ht", "https://google.com")

# our new function takes not only word boundary from the left side,
# but also a white space or string beginning
removeWords2 <- function(x, words) {
  gsub(sprintf("(\\b|\\s|^)(%s)\\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE), collapse = "|")), "", x)
}

# remove words
data <- removeWords2(tweets, remove)

# check that
head(data)
#> [1] "WOW it is cool!" "WOW it is cool!" "WOW it is cool!" "WOW it is cool!"
#> [5] "WOW it is cool!" "WOW it is cool!"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It's pretty fast and works as expected, and moreover you can adjust it to your own needs.